# Convert an SQL into pymongo query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Document prototype:

```
{
    "d": "D", 
    "g": {
        "c": "C", 
        "a": "A", 
        "b": "B"
    }, 
    "e": "E", 
    "f": "F"
}
```

What would be the equivalent of:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d from Table WHERE d='D' AND e='E' GROUP BY a
```

in mongodb using pymongo?

The following query returns objects:

```
db.<collection>.find({'d': 'D'}, {'g.c': 1, 'g.a': 1, 'g.b': 1, 'd': 1, '_id': 0})
```

But, the following doesn't:

```
db.<collection>.aggregate([{$match:{"d":"D", "e":"E"}},
                           {$group:{_id:"$g.a"}}])
```

It returns an empty list, not even a query(cursor) object.

Also, how could I include $project into it so that I may restrict the output to the fields of a, b ,c d only?

Note I 've created the collection so as to filter e='E'.

Comment: Normally we don't answer these types of questions that demonstrate no effort on your part to fix the problem, however, this time appears some one has answered

Comment: Sorry if it looks that way. But effort has been put into it. One must not be so quick and sure at judging things. At least when they can't bother to approach the solution themselves. Sorry again if too rude.
@Sammaye

Comment: Maybe if you showed effort I would be "bothered", also your edit, it works perfectly fine: `> db.z.insert({d:'D',g:{c:'C',a:'A',b:'B'},e:'E',f:'F'})
> db.z.aggregate([{$match:{d:'D',e:'E'}},{$group:{_id:'$g.a'}}])
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : "A" } ], "ok" : 1 }` Also that is not valid pymongo syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your query is not a valid SQL.

You have to quote strings

```
SELECT a, b, c, d
from Table
WHERE d='D' AND e='E'
GROUP BY a
```

And still this query will work only in MySQL. For ANSI SQL (and most implementations) you should specify aggregates for your columns, like

```
SELECT a, min(b) as b, max(c) as c
from Table
WHERE d='D' AND e='E'
GROUP BY a
```

then your mongodb query would be like

```
db.<your collection>.aggregate([
   {$match:{"d":"D", "e":"E"}},
   {$group:{_id:"$g.a", b: { $min: "$g.b"}, c: {$max:"$g.c"}}}
])
```

if you want an array of a, b, c, d values, this should work:

```
db.<your collection>.aggregate([
   {$match:{"d": "D", "e": "E"}},
   {
       $group: {
            _id: "$g.a",
            data: {$push: {"a": "$g.a", "b": "$g.b", "c": "$g.c", "d": "$d"}}
       }
   }
])
```

Just tested this code - it works, here's python code:

```
>>> cl = MongoClient()
>>> coll = cl["local"]["test3"]
>>> res = coll.aggregate([{"$match":{"d": "D", "e": "E"}},{"$group":{"_id":"$g.a", "data": {"$push":{"a":"$g.a", "b":"$g.b", "c":"$g.c", "d":"$d"}}}}])
>>> res["result"]
[{'_id': 'A', 'data': [{'a': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'B', 'd': 'D'}, {'a': 'A', 'c': 'K', 'b': u'V', 'd': 'D'}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, for the correction in SQL. However, quote was left behind intended, as an obvious thing. But that shouldn't had been.

BTW, I don't have any requirement of AnsiSQL query here. I just have to get objects having a,b,c,d in it grouped by a and d should be D and e should be E. Could you render the query without the min and max functions?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the answer by @RomanPekar does actually work:

```
> db.z.insert({d:'D',g:{c:'C',a:'A',b:'B'},e:'E',f:'F'})
> db.z.aggregate([{$match:{d:'D',e:'E'}},{$group:{_id:'$g.a'}}])
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : "A" } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

The problem is, most likely, that you are trying to do this in python without changing the syntax. Instead you would run this in python:

```
db.z.aggregate([{"$match":{"d":"D","e":"E"}},{"$group":{"_id":"$g.a"}}])
```

For reference: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html